# Select a value in dropdownlist in razor MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

How can a I set the selected value of a DropdownList in Razor, inside an array of model object? Example:

```
@foreach (var model in Model.Courses)
{
   ....
   <td>
       @Html.DropDownList(**** set the selected value from model.Order, from my Model.Positions list ****)
   </td>
   ....
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
@foreach (var model in Model.Courses)
{
   ....
   <td>
                          //Control Name,  Options,     Selected Value
       @Html.DropDownList("NameOfControl", ListOfItems, model.Value)
   </td>
   ....
}
```

Comment: -1 because when pressing F12 on the DropDownList helper, the comment for the third parameter says "optionLabel: The text for a default empty item. This parameter can be null."
So , because it will not actually SELECT your value, it will just display  it as a "default empty item". If you make a POST after this, the value you have "selected" this way will not be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Better try to set selected option in the datasource itself using SelectList

```
    Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    list.Add("Value1", "1");
    list.Add("Value2", "2");
    list.Add("Value3", "3");
    var selectList = new SelectList(list,
              "Value", "Key", 
              "2"); // selected item's value "Value2" is selected.
    ViewData["SelectedValue"] = selectList;

    @Html.DropDownList("ddlValues", (SelectList)ViewData["SelectedValue"]) )
```